How to send messages from client to server using async tcp in python?
I am trying to create a GUI communication app that uses async tcp. But ı couldn't figure out these 2 things:

how to send messages from client side to server side
Why cannot I use the same reader and writer once I create a connection for client side. What I mean is when I do not use this line in send_messages_to_server() function reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8888) after receiving 1 message client does not accept any more messages.

async def connect_client():

    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8888)

    print("Client connected")
    return reader, writer

async def send_message_to_server(reader, writer, message: str) -> None:
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8888)

    writer.write(message.encode())
    await writer.drain()

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()


async def read_messages(queue: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    server_task = None
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        match message:
            case "Server started":
                server_task = asyncio.create_task(run_server())
            case "Client started":
                reader, writer = await connect_client()

Here you can find my whole code:
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import asyncio
from threading import Thread


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._async_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self._asyncio_event_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(1039, 643)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 100, 411, 51))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        # Send Button
        self.sendButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.sendButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 370, 141, 41))
        self.sendButton.setObjectName("sendButton")

        # Combo-box
        self.type1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.type1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 50, 111, 31))
        self.type1.setObjectName("type")
        self.type1.addItem("")
        self.type1.addItem("")

        # Type Label
        self.typeLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.typeLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 50, 51, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.typeLabel.setFont(font)
        self.typeLabel.setObjectName("typeLabel")
        self.messageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.messageLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 110, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)

        # Message Label
        self.messageLabel.setFont(font)
        self.messageLabel.setMidLineWidth(5)
        self.messageLabel.setObjectName("messageLabel")

        # Connection Button
        self.connectionButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.connectionButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(610, 40, 141, 41))
        self.connectionButton.setObjectName("connectionButton")

        # Display Texts
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 170, 411, 101))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")

        self.receivedMessagesLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.receivedMessagesLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 210, 171, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.receivedMessagesLabel.setFont(font)
        self.receivedMessagesLabel.setObjectName("receivedMessagesLabel")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1039, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(self)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(self)

        self.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.sendButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send"))
        self.type1.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "TCP Server"))
        self.type1.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "TCP Server"))
        self.type1.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "TCP Client"))
        self.typeLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Type"))
        self.messageLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Message"))
        self.connectionButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect"))
        self.receivedMessagesLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Received Messages"))



        '''
        self.connectionButton.pressed.connect(
            lambda: self.send_message_to_event_loop("start_server")
        )
        '''
        self.connectionButton.pressed.connect(self.connection)
        self.sendButton.pressed.connect(lambda: self.send_message_to_event_loop(self.lineEdit.text()))
        
        '''
        self.sendButton.pressed.connect(
            lambda: self.send_message_to_event_loop(self.lineEdit.text())
        )
        '''
    
    def connection(self):
        self.conType = self.type1.currentText()
        if self.conType == "TCP Server":
            self.send_message_to_event_loop("Server started")
        elif self.conType == "TCP Client":
            print("Client")
            self.send_message_to_event_loop("Client started")


    def send_message_to_event_loop(self, message: str) -> None:
        """Send the `asyncio` event loop's queue a message by using the coroutine
        `put` and sending it to run on the `asyncio` event loop, putting the message
        on the queue inside the event loop. This must be done because `asyncio.Queue`
        is not threadsafe.
        """   
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            coro=self._async_queue.put(message),
            loop=self._asyncio_event_loop,
        )


async def handle_client(
    reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter
) -> None:
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info("peername")

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()


async def run_server():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, "127.0.0.1", 8888)
    async with server:
        print("Started server")
        await server.serve_forever()


async def connect_client():

    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8888)

    print("Client connected")
    return reader, writer

async def send_message_to_server(reader, writer, message: str) -> None:
    # Lazily create a new connection every time just for demonstration
    # purposes
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8888)

    writer.write(message.encode())
    await writer.drain()

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()


async def read_messages(queue: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    server_task = None
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        match message:
            case "Server started":
                server_task = asyncio.create_task(run_server())
            case "Client started":
                reader, writer = await connect_client()
            case msg:
                await send_message_to_server(reader, writer, msg)


async def async_main(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    # Launch the tasks to sit around and listen to messages
    await asyncio.gather(read_messages(queue))


def start_asyncio_event_loop(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> None:
    """Starts the given `asyncio` loop on whatever the current thread is"""
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.set_debug(enabled=True)
    loop.run_forever()


def run_event_loop(queue: asyncio.Queue, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> None:
    """Runs the given `asyncio` loop on a separate thread, passing the queue to the
    event loop for any other thread to send messages to the event loop. The main
    coroutine that is launched on the event loop is `async_main`.
    """
    thread = Thread(target=start_asyncio_event_loop, args=(loop,), daemon=True)
    thread.start()

    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(async_main(queue), loop=loop)


def run_application(application: QApplication):
    application.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    async_queue = window._async_queue
    asyncio_event_loop = window._asyncio_event_loop

    run_event_loop(queue=async_queue, loop=asyncio_event_loop)
    sys.exit(run_application(application))




Why are you calling asyncio.open_connection() twice?

As i have mentioned in my question if i do not call second one after one message client stop reading messages. I do not know why but it doesn't use the same reader over and over again. I have to create a new one every time.
